# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic

estoy teniendo creando una app con ionic, react y capacitor, trataba de probar el plugin vibrator para las notificaciones pero al compilarlo y probarlo desde el teléfono en android studio me general el siguiente error

Error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { Plugins, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Vibration } from '@ionic-native/vibration/ngx';

interface Props extends React.Props<ControlVibratorComponent> {

}

export default class ControlVibratorComponent extends React.Component<Props>{
constructor(props: any, private vibration: Vibration) {
    super(props);

}

changeNotificationState(e: any) {
    if (e.detail.value > 0) {
        console.log('vibrando');
        // this.vibration.vibrate([2000, 1000, 2000]);
        console.log(this.vibration);
        this.vibration.vibrate(2000);

    } else {
        console.log('stop');
        this.vibration.vibrate(0);
    }
}
}
```

Espero alguien pueda colaborarme ya que no hay mucha información respecto a este plugin

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque `this.vibration = undefined`.

Esto pasa porque si bien estas recibiendo el vibration en el constructor no lo estas asignado a ninguna variable de la clase.

Deberias hacer dentro del constructor algo como:

```
constructor(props: any, private vibration: Vibration) {
    super(props);
    this.vibration = vibration;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado!